# Installing Open Project 7 (Apache error: Service Unavailable)

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, openproject

Here is the original question: https://community.openproject.com/topics/7851

I'm trying to install Open Project 7 in a brand new Ubuntu instance at Digital Ocean.

I've follow the instructions at https://www.openproject.org/download-and-installation/, but it's not working.

After the complete of installation and the run of the `openproject configure` command, i have selected options to install both MySQL and Apache server. When it's all done, i'm unable to connect to my server.

My enviroment:

Ubuntu 16.04

http://159.203.191.172

At logs, i can see two strange messages.

First:

`bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn)`

Second is a warning:

`WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash#name defined at /opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/omniauth-8385bc0da47e/lib/omniauth/auth_hash.rb:34. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-06-13T01:01:17.860764 #25822]`

I don't know if the warning is related to problem, but i think that the unicorn problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

I suspected that the package had some problems so i decided to install it using manual installation. The newest documentation i found was an old Ubuntu 14 step-to-step tutorial, adapted from older versions of Open Project. I decided to follow it and after a lot of adaptations i got able to finish the installation process.

This is the tutorial: https://github.com/opf/openproject-ce/blob/stable/7/docs/installation/manual/README.md

Now I'm writing another step-to-step tutorial based on it, modifying all required steps to perform a clean installation on Ubuntu 16.